# pager_query() - How to fetch only 100 records with a pagination 10 items per page?

Tags: 6, database, paging

```
$result = pager_query($query, 10, 0, NULL, $args);
```

Currently with above code , I am getting all **results** with **10 items** per page. But I need to display only first 100 records , with 10 items per page. Is this possible with [pager_query()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!pager.inc/function/pager_query/6)  or any alternate solution using plain **PHP** and **MySQL**?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a `$count_query` argument to `pager_query()`, which you can use to control the overall count:

e.g.

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM my_table';
$count_sql = 'SELECT COUNT(id) FROM my_table LIMIT 100';

$result = pager_query($sql, 10, 0, $count_sql);
```

Comment: Tried that , no effect, is there anything to be added additionally?

Comment: I've never actually tried that, it just made sense logically. I don't think there's any other approach to getting the standard `pager_query()` to do what you want, if the above doesn't work you'll have to go for a custom implementation

Comment: Try changing to `LIMIT 0, 100`.

Answer (score 0):

Replace '$args' with '100' in pager_query() and check.

Answer (score 0):

**If you need to supply any argument to your query just add them after all the **pager_query** arguments like so:**

**Example Query:**

```
$query = "SELECT heading, summary, publish_date FROM {news} WHERE category_id = %d ORDER BY publish_date DESC";

$result = pager_query($query, 100, 0, NULL, $cat_id);
```

So, for the **pager_query** example above let me explain the arguments:

1. **1st arg ($query)** = The query to be executed.
2. **2nd arg (10)** = $limit The number of query results to display per page.
3. **3rd arg (0)** = $element The integer number of the pager we are working with.
4. **4th arg (NULL)** = $count_query Just put NULL which is the default for this variable.
5. **5th arg ($cat_id)** = The argument that needs to be passed to the query itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$results = $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')   
          ->entityCondition('bundle', 'your_content_type')
          ->fieldCondition('field_village_schedule_state', 'value', 'your_value','=')
         $_GET['village'],'=')      
           ->range(0,100)  
           ->execute(); 

  if (isset($results['node'])) {
       $nodes = node_load_multiple(array_keys($results['node']));
       foreach ($nodes as $row) 
        {
          // Your Code Here for dispaly.
        }
     }
```